# Very slow insert speed using sqlite's .import command line

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to import a database with around 4.5 million entries, 350 fields, and 2 indexes (I didn't design this) from a .csv into a sqlite database.  Most of the performance issues I read about people having involve not using batch transactions and various things like this but I imagined using the sqlite command line import would be as fast as possible.  Yet I'm only getting around ~150 inserts per second.  Is there a way to speed this up somehow?

As far as what I've tried I've recreated the table schema without the two indices and I've tried setting PRAGMA Synchronous to off based on recommendations I read from googling but neither of these helped, I still get the same inserts/minute.

For whatever reason the first 5,000 inserts seem to happen nearly instantly but after that it slows down to around 150/second.

Comment: Please post more information including example(s) of what you have tried, etc.

Comment: Does the table have any indexes/constraints/triggers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777463/sqlite-is-very-slow-when-performing-import-on-a-large-table

Comment: In addition to turning off Synchronous, try these and if it doesn't fix the problem visit the question that @Mark-H mentioned and linked to previously.
`PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF`
`PRAGMA cache_size = 7500000`
`PRAGMA temp_store = 2`

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can try doing to speed up the import.

1. Turn off journaling - PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF
2. If you're importing to a VM up the resources till your done with the import
3. Maybe convert your csv to a dump file as that's native to SQLite and should import quicker

It none of that helps you can try using the sqlite-utils Python library. That will allow you to use the import_csv function which might result in a faster import. At the end of the day your working with a huge dataset.